# Multiple Radio button save To database in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to make questionnaire to show the test has done.
But, the answer button can't upload the answer to database.

I'm really confused.
This is my code named `soal.php` (thats means question.php)

```
<?php
include "header2.php";
?>
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "magang";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * from kuesioner";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  echo "<div style='width:100%; border: 1px solid #EBEBEB; overflow:scroll;height:900px;'>";
  echo '<table width="100%">';
  $urut = 0;
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id_soal=$row["id_soal"];
    $soal=$row["soal"];
    $pilihan_a=$row["A"];
    $pilihan_b=$row["B"];
    $pilihan_c=$row["C"];
    $pilihan_d=$row["D"];

    ?>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="jawab.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="id_user[]" value=<?php echo $id_soal; ?>>
      <input type="hidden" name="id_soal[]" value=<?php echo $id_soal; ?>>  
      <input type="hidden" name="jumlah" value=<?php echo $result->num_rows; ?>>
      <tr>
        <td width="17"><font color="#000000"><?php echo $urut=$urut+1; ?></font></td>
        <td width="430"><font color="#000000"><?php echo "$soal"; ?></font></td>
      </tr>
        <td height="21"><font color="#000000">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td><font color="#000000">
          A.  <input name="pilihan[<?php echo $id_soal; ?>]" type="radio" value="1"> 
          <?php echo "$pilihan_a";?></font> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><font color="#000000">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td><font color="#000000">
        B. <input name="pilihan[<?php echo $id_soal; ?>]" type="radio" value="2"> 
        <?php echo "$pilihan_b";?></font> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><font color="#000000">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td><font color="#000000">
        C.  <input name="pilihan[<?php echo $id_soal; ?>]" type="radio" value="3"> 
        <?php echo "$pilihan_c";?></font> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><font color="#000000">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td><font color="#000000">
        D.   <input name="pilihan[<?php echo $id_soal; ?>]" type="radio" value="4"> 
        <?php echo "$pilihan_d";?></font> </td>
      </tr>


    <?php 
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();


?>

<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Jawab" onclick="return confirm('Apakah Anda yakin dengan jawaban Anda?')"></center></td>

</tr>
</table>
</form>
</p>
</div>
```

But I already tried to make button for the answer, but I can't.
I can't create the right code for the answer button.

This my code for answers, named `jawab.php` (answer.php)

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("magang");

$id_soal=$_POST["id_soal"];
$pilihan = $_POST["pilihan"];
$no = 0 ;

foreach ($_POST['id_soal'] as $row) {
  echo "<br>";
  $a = $id_soal[$no];
  echo $a;
  echo "<b r>";
  echo $pilihan[$a];
  $no = $no + 1 ;
}   

?>
```

Comment: The `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is outright [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Also, the problem could be that you are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`. See [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php) for more info, and use `mysqli` for the `jawab.php` page instead, ensuring that you also use [**parameterised queries**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL Injection :)

Comment: but int soal.php There is no wrong code  right? because its work,just the button answer itss not work

Comment: i read the article said i must use array for multiinsert to database,but i confuse because have the radiobutton.Can you help me?

Comment: You code looks like a mess. Seriously. There is no  `<table>` opening tag and a missing `<tr>` tag. -- The `<form name="form1" ...>` opening tag is in the `while` loop... And the `</form>` is outside. So you are having **many** forms named "form1", but only the last is closed and is including the `submit` button. -- Just start with a clean up on this.

Comment: Your code is really a mess.. Rearrange your code and add broken tags

Comment: echo '<table width="100%">'; is it not table opening? thanks,i already fix about <tr>.

Comment: how about jawab.php guys? help me please